# How to distinguish servers in node js with a unique server property/value?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server

I have a project currently works on a single server. Now more regions will be added, and I update server files via private git repository, but each has a different configuration (like database connections)
I want to be able to access a unique server value (maybe mac address?) to distinguish servers so corresponding settings file can be loaded. Servers are ubuntu.

What is the best practice? I tried os.hostname() but it is not unique (usually like: ubuntu-fra-8gb)
Or should I just go with ENV values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option is to provide an `instanceName` to the server through command line parameters or environment variables when you launch it; than using that name as configuration key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I decided to go with an environment value in /etc/profile based on your feedback. I hope this is what you meant. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is @siniradam